# How to replace hidden input with global variable to hold data

Tags: javascript, html, variables

Currently I save data in input `type="hidden"` and access them from any JS script using `getDocumentById("sourceJson")`. For example:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="sourceJson" name="sourceJson" >
    
var val = document.getElementById("sourceJson").value
```

But it forces me to scatter many hidden inputs in the HTML file. What is good replacement to hold data and have access to it from all scripts? Some kind of global variables that can also be submitted to the server.

Comment: Like [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)?

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a variable in any normal script it should be available from any other script.

```
<html><body>
<script>
    var varOne = "Hello ..";
</script>
<script>
    var varTwo = ".. world";
</script>
<script>
    alert(varOne + varTwo);
</script>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

**To Store array `data` we can use `localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data));`**

```
const data = localStorage.getItem("data")? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data")):[];


function setData(name, value){
  data.push({"name":name, "value":value});
  localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data));
}
function getData(name){
  var ret = undefined;
  for(var x = 0; x < data.length; x++){
    if(data[x].name == name){
      ret = data[x].value;
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
```